# Symfony framework problem with creating controller

Tags: php, symfony

I just started to learn Symfony framework and I got stuck on very begging.
I created with composer with following commands:

1. composer require symfony/maker-bundle --dev
2. composer require annotations
3. php bin/console make:controller ToDoListController.php

Code looks good, but when I try to open this controller I am getting an error message:

`Uncaught Error: Class 'Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony44\src\Controller\ToDoListController.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony44\src\Controller\ToDoListController.php on line 9.`

I am using xampp as a local server, symfony 4.4

Has anyone encountered with this problem?

Comment: If you've just started to learn Symfony framework, why you didn't start from the latest stable version? (5.4). By the way, what is the xampp version? (I strongly encourage you to use a virtual environment to develop to avoid many headache)

Comment: First off I am pretty sure you created a Symfony app first by using either `symfony new symfony44` or `composer create-project symfony/skeleton symfony44`.  Strange that you failed to mention this step in your question.  Secondly, in order to use the apache server you would also need to install the symfony/apache package.  But save your self some trouble and just use the symfony development server with `symfony server:start`.  And while 5.4 is not actually released yet it does make sense to learn with 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

Please install symfony using the symfony app. Download the app for windows from https://symfony.com/download.
Open the windows command prompt.
type the following commands

```
symfony new project-name --full
cd project-name
symfony serve
```

symfony serve starts your development server. Use apache when your app is deployed. With the symfony app you can use https. This method of symfony installation is easy and it is good for those new to symfony. With the --full option maker bundle and all other important bundles are installed for you. You can just start creating controllers